# Getting error while trying to deploy blockchain inside of an IBM Container Service

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, blockchain

For deploying blockchain in an IBM Cloud Container Service, I am following the steps outlined on https://github.ibm.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-container-service/blob/v1.0.0/cs-offerings/free/README.md

while running the script "create_all.sh" I am getting the following error repeatedly:

Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Waiting for createchannel container to be Completed

I have already tried starting the procedure from the first step all over again. But no luck so far. Not sure why I keep getting this error.

Any help or hint in this regard will be of great value to me. Thanks!

Comment: I tested this on a free cluster without other resources in the environment and it worked. Are you seeing any other errors during the create channel section? Are there any deployments/pods in an error state when you list them: `kubectl get deploy` or `kubectl get pods`?

Comment: @MichaelPetersen Thanks for looking into it. The error is resolved now. There is a step in which we need to set the value of an environment variable KUBECONFIG. The yml file name there was incorrect(the tutorial page had a hardcoded file name). The file name should be the yml file that we downloaded earlier.

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks for the followup.

Comment: @MichaelPetersen I have set up composer and blockchain inside of container service. Now, How do I access this chaincode from postman? I am struggling to find the peer URL/IP address to be used here? Do you have any clues?

Comment: Are you talking about this URL- Ensure that the PEER_ADDRESS address variable is properly set with the peer's URL (blockchain-org1peer1:5010). Also, you may want to ask a new question since you've hit a different issue. You may want to tag Kubernetes as well to get a broader audience.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable KUBECONFIG  should be pointing to the correct "kube config yml" file.